# using Func<string, bool>, how can I split on a character then count the length of those values within a function

Tags: c#

Essentially, I need to split a string like `"aaaaa.bbbbbbbb.cccccc"` on the . and then count the length of the split values using a function.

```
Func<string, bool> length = f => f.Split(".").Length > 1;
```

pretty much this but instead of counting the length of the split array, I need to count how many letters per entry of the array and see if they are over a certain length.

Comment: `Func<string, bool>` won't give you that.

Comment: Don't you want `Func<string, char, IEnumerable<int>>`?

Comment: @Jodrell that won't return multiple things

Comment: @DanielA.White it will return a sequence of integers.

Comment: yawn, `Func<string, char, IEnumerable<int>> getLengths = (input, separator) => input.Split(separator).Select(s => s.Length);` or something like that.

Comment: @DanielA.White editted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a boolean answer, then it's either one of the following (depdending on if you want at least one substring with length > 1 or you want all of them:

```
    Func<string, bool> length1 = f => f.Split('.').Any(s => s.Length > 1);
    Func<string, bool> length2 = f => f.Split('.').All(s => s.Length > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
string input = "aaaaa.bbbbbbbb.cccccc";
var parts = input.Split('.');
var lengths = parts.Select(e=>e.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean per letter:
aaaaa.bbbbbbbb.cccccc -> a = 5, b = 8, c = 6

`Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> length = f => f.Split('.').Select(a => a.Length)`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need to take a string, split it *only* by the delimiter '.', and then count to see if each split value is greater than 1.

If so, you can use the following:

```
Func<string, bool> length = str => str.Split('.').All(s => s.Length > 1);
```

This will first split the string by your delimiter, then iterate on all of the values to check if they are greater than 1.

Quick test case:

```
string test1 = "aaa.b.ccccccc";
string test2 = "aaaaaa.bbb.c";
string test3 = "aaa.bbb.ccccc";

Console.WriteLine(length(test1)); // false, as b is 1, not greater
Console.WriteLine(length(test2)); // false, for similar reasons
Console.WriteLine(length(test3)); // true, all are greater
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this [[Example reference]](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SXQsO):

```
Func<string, List<int>> length = f => f.Split('.').Select(x=>x.Length).ToList();
```

And call the method like this:

```
string inputStr = "aaaaa.bbbbbbbb.cccccc";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",length(inputStr))); // prints 5,8,6
```

Please note: the second parameter in the `Func` denotes the return type, Here in the example I used it as `List<int>` that's why I added `.ToList()` at the end of the code. You can change the return types accordingly. If you are ok with `IEnumerable<int>` then

```
Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> length = f => f.Split('.').Select(x=>x.Length)
```

is enough.

Comment: OP wants to count the amount in each entry. This won't calculate the length of each array, only the array itself.

Comment: @Frontear, thanks for correcting me, I just updated the post, can you please review the same

Comment: @Jodrell: thanks for correcting me, I just updated the post, can you please review the same

Comment: @JohneyBronswicAppleton: add  `using System.Linq;` in the using section

Comment: Why `ToList()`?

Comment: @Jodrell: That depends on the output you want, if you remove `.ToList()` return type also needs to changed as  `IEnumerable<int>`

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a func delegate:

```
Func<string, Tuple<string[], int[]>> length = (str) => {
    string[] stringParts = str.Split('.');
    int[] countLetters = stringParts.Select(s => s.Length).ToArray();
    return new Tuple<string[], int[]>(stringParts, countLetters);
};

string input = "aaaaa.bbbbbbbb.cccccc";

var res = length(input);
string[] strs = res.Item1;
int[] countLetter = res.Item2;


for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strs[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(countLetter[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
aaaaa
5
bbbbbbbb
8
cccccc
6
```

An extension method would perhaps be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about you write a method that returns list of strings that above the length you specify, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSplittedAboveLimit(string inputString,int limit)
{
   var splitted = inputString.Split(".");
   foreach(var input in splitted)
   {
      if(input.Length > limit)
      {
          yield return input; 
      }
   }
}
```